# Enum, constants, or other to represent chess pieces

Tags: c#, enum, constants, chess

I'm learning C# and I decided to write a chess program to help me practice the concepts I'm learning in my book. I started the Board class tonight, which is going to handle 1) the board state and 2) checking if moves are legal.

I feel like I need to give careful consideration to how I represent the board. I started with a list of constants:

```
// CONSTANTS
private const sbyte EMPTYSQUARE = 0;
private const sbyte WKING = 1;
private const sbyte WQUEEN = 2;
private const sbyte WROOK = 3;
private const sbyte WBISHOP = 4;
private const sbyte WKNIGHT = 5;
private const sbyte WPAWN = 6;
private const sbyte BKING = 7;
private const sbyte BQUEEN = 8;
private const sbyte BROOK = 9;
private const sbyte BBISHOP = 10;
private const sbyte BKNIGHT = 11;
private const sbyte BPAWN = 12;

private const sbyte GAMEINPROGRESS = 0;
private const sbyte CHECKMATEWHITE = 1;
private const sbyte CHECKMATEBLACK = 2;
private const sbyte NOLEGALMOVESDRAW = 3;
private const sbyte THREEMOVEDRAW = 4;
private const sbyte FIFTYMOVEDRAW = 5;
private const sbyte WHITERESIGNED = 6;
private const sbyte BLACKRESIGNED = 7;

// VARIABLES
private sbyte[,] board =
{
    {9, 11, 10, 8,  7,  10, 11, 9},
    {12,12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,12},
    {0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
    {0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
    {0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
    {0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
    {6, 6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6},
    {3, 5,  4,  2,  1,  4,  5,  3}
};
```

Then I realized I could use an `enum` here, which I hear is good practice so you don't go mixing up your "magic numbers":

```
private enum Piece
{
    EMPTY, WKING, WQUEEN, WROOK, WBISHOP, WKNIGHT, WPAWN, BKING, BQUEEN, BROOK, BBISHOP, BKNIGHT, BPAWN
}

private enum State
{
    GAMEINPROGRESS, CHECKMATEWHITE, CHECKMATEBLACK, NOLEGALMOVEDRAW, THREEMOVEDRAW, FIFTYMOVEDRAW, WHITERESIGNED, BLACKRESIGNED
}
```

I then go to declare the board array and I had to use this ugly-looking monstrosity:

```
private sbyte[,] board =
{
    {(sbyte)Piece.BROOK, (sbyte)Piece.BKNIGHT, (sbyte)Piece.BBISHOP, (sbyte)Piece.BQUEEN, (sbyte)Piece.BKING, (sbyte)Piece.BBISHOP, (sbyte)Piece.BKNIGHT, (sbyte)Piece.BROOK},
    {(sbyte)Piece.BPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.BPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.BPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.BPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.BPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.BPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.BPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.BPAWN},
    {(sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY},
    {(sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY},
    {(sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY},
    {(sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY, (sbyte)Piece.EMPTY},
    {(sbyte)Piece.WPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.WPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.WPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.WPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.WPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.WPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.WPAWN, (sbyte)Piece.WPAWN},
    {(sbyte)Piece.WROOK, (sbyte)Piece.WKNIGHT, (sbyte)Piece.WBISHOP, (sbyte)Piece.WQUEEN, (sbyte)Piece.WKING, (sbyte)Piece.WBISHOP, (sbyte)Piece.WKNIGHT, (sbyte)Piece.WROOK}
};
```

It's really making me second-guess whether or not I want to keep using `enum`. That's a lot of typing and typecasting just to program in one chess board.

What do you think? Should I go constants or `enum`s?

And while we're at it, what do you think of my choice of data structure for a chess board? Are there faster structures? Are there smaller structures? (I only need to store numbers 0 through 12) Should I enlarge the array to help me compute off-the-board knight moves? Should I be using a different data structure entirely?

Comment: I'd suggest making a class of Piece and extending that for each type. Then making instances of each piece needed. Each piece type is a pretty significant part of chess. You can make Piece an abstract class with a move method. Then override that in each piece type

Comment: This is crying out for a couple of uses of a Factory design pattern: ChessPieceFactory to make the pieces and ChessBoardFactory to put them in the right places.

Comment: One of the reasons Enums were added to Java was to improve on the verbose and type-unsafe `static final int` idiom. Unfortunately they weren't added until JDK 1.5, so there's a lot of legacy code (i.e. the Java standard library itself) that uses the old way, and people have a habit of copying it. C# added them from the start to avoid this.

Comment: Did anybody want to give the Factory Design Pattern a shot? I'm curious to see what that would look like, and what the advantages of it are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it definitely makes sense to use an object hierarchy here. What's the difference between a black and a white pawn? Its colour! (which will affect which way it can move relative to the board).

All pieces must have exactly one colour, and we have two to chose from:

```
public enum PieceColour
{
    White = 0,
    Black = 1
}
```

As we've already reasoned, all pieces have to have a colour and unless you've got a defective set, none of the pieces can change colour midway through. Sounds like we have an invariant that we want all pieces to obey. We can lock that up with a base class:

```
public abstract class Piece
{
    private readonly PieceColour colour;

    public PieceColour Colour { get { return colour; } }

    protected Piece(PieceColour colour)
    {
        this.colour = colour;
    }
}
```

By making the piece class abstract, we are saying "you can't have a generic Piece, you have to have a specialized subclass". Let's see what that some of those might look like:

```
public class Pawn : Piece
{
    public Pawn(PieceColour colour)
        : base(colour)
    {
    }
}

public class Rook : Piece
{
    public Rook(PieceColour colour)
        : base(colour)
    {
    }
}

public class Knight : Piece
{
    public Knight(PieceColour colour)
        : base(colour)
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can start playing around with a board. To be completely honest, I haven't thought enough about it to figure out how I'd really want it to look but something like the following would be enough to get along with. `Tuple<int, int>` is just a convenient wrapper around two ints (the coordinates of a space).

```
public class Board
{
    private Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Piece> currentState;

    public static Board CreateNewBoard()
    {
        var board = new Board();

        board.currentState = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Piece> 
        {                      // x, y
            { new Tuple<int, int>(0, 0), new Rook(PieceColour.White) },
            { new Tuple<int, int>(1, 0), new Knight(PieceColour.White) }
            // etc. 
        };

        return board;
    }
}
```

}

Any common behaviour you should find behind all pieces you should add it to the base class `Piece`, for example they can all move...

**Edit**

I thought the above made it clear that I think there should be an abstract method on the piece class that deals with movement. I didn't commit to making a suggestion on the signature of the method because I haven't seen what you're doing currently. I have the impression OP intends on "moving pieces" entirely within the board class.

Comment: Extracting color to an enum is a good suggestions, but if there is no `move` method in the `Piece` class then I'd not use inheritance there, just another enum. I'd really like to see an abstract `move` method in the `Piece` class though, so that each piece can handle it's own movement.

Comment: That's what I was alluding to in the comment at the bottom. "For example, they can all move..."

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I just wanted to add that without that method, the class shouldn't be abstract.

Answer (score 7):

Using enums instead of constants is a good fit if you deal with a familiy of something, like you do with `Piece`.

As we don't know how the remaining code looks like, it is only a guessing what would be the best fit for your case at all.

If your `Piece`'es also need some logic (properties or methods), you should go with what @[Evorlor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/61072/evorlor) has [commented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73721/enum-constants-or-other-to-represent-chess-pieces-c#comment133944_73721).

For using the enum with your `board` you can simply change the datatype of the `board`

```
private Piece[,] board =
{
    {Piece.BROOK, Piece.BKNIGHT, Piece.BBISHOP, Piece.BQUEEN, Piece.BKING, Piece.BBISHOP, Piece.BKNIGHT, Piece.BROOK},
    {Piece.BPAWN, Piece.BPAWN, Piece.BPAWN, Piece.BPAWN, Piece.BPAWN, Piece.BPAWN, Piece.BPAWN, Piece.BPAWN},
    {Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY},
    {Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY},
    {Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY},
    {Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY, Piece.EMPTY},
    {Piece.WPAWN, Piece.WPAWN, Piece.WPAWN, Piece.WPAWN, Piece.WPAWN, Piece.WPAWN, Piece.WPAWN, Piece.WPAWN},
    {Piece.WROOK, Piece.WKNIGHT, Piece.WBISHOP, Piece.WQUEEN, Piece.WKING, Piece.WBISHOP, Piece.WKNIGHT, Piece.WROOK}
};
```

no typecasting is needed.

What you shouldn't do is shortening variable names or enums. Also, using `PascalCasing` casing, as one should use for public enums, would increase readability IMHO. So e.g. `BKNIGHT` should be `BlackKnight`

Comment: Personally I think the piece colour and piece type should be separate, and then piece itself would be a struct combining both. Good call on the PascalCasing though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/4x252001%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Another possible enhancement to this route would be to make it a flags enum, where the first bit is the existence of the piece, the second is the color, and the remaining are the piece. I would never do this, but would favor objects. Still, it might be good to know.